# How to manage app versions with AWS ElasticBeanstalk Docker platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

So I have successfully launched an app and an environment in AWS ElasticBeanstalk, using private image repository. I can build and push new versions of my app to the repository, and then run `eb deploy` to have it pull and update the EC2 instances. Great!

But how can I manage versions? What if I want to rollback to some previous version of the app? In the current setup there's only really one image in the repo `someapp:latest`. This is also how it's specified in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Now the eb cli and the web console allow me to deploy previous version of the app, to an environment.

Now but wouldn't this just pull the `someapp:latest` from my private image repo and deploy that?

Should I start version tagging the images I push, and modify the `docker-compose.yml` file with every new version? Seems a little rough.

Comment: You could push a previous image with the `latest` tag.